# What's the grammar behind 飲み足りる?

Tags: grammar

I've seen in subtitle of a tv show "ただ飲み足りないだけ"

I know there is に足りる form to mean "to be enough" but it should have been 飲むに足りない.

Is there any other grammar point I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatically, it's a [*compound verb* (複合動詞)](https://db4.ninjal.ac.jp/vvlexicon/en/). `pre-masu-form + 足りる` means "to V enough" or "to V to one's heart's content". The following compounds are used, although they may not be listed in all dictionaries.

- 食べ足りる (5 hits on BCCWJ) ・ 食い足りる
- 飲み足りる (18 hits on BCCWJ)
- 寝足りる (6 hits on BCCWJ)
- し足りる ・ やり足りる

These may not be very formal, but they are not particularly slangy to me, either.

満ち足りる is another compound verb that should be listed in any dictionary.

---

By the way, `attributive-form + に + 足りる` means "to be worth V-ing" or "to be good enough to V" rather than "to V enough". 飲むに足りる means "to be worth drinking".

> 飲むに足りない日本酒
>     *sake* that is not worth drinking